# Legend key features overridden - remove fill and diagonal line

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a line plot here with a grey rectangle shaded from x axis values 50-160. The additional plotting of this rectangle appears to be overriding my legend key specifications, filling the legend key with grey with a diagonal line through the key that is the color of the variable. I have tried both of the following with no success:

```
theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white",colour = "white")) + 
theme(legend.background = element_blank())
```

and

```
guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)))
theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

Does this have something to do with `inherit.aes = FALSE` in my last plot line?

Any suggestions?
Many thanks!

```
rect=data.frame (xmin=50, xmax=160, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)  
p1=ggplot(p1, aes(x=JDY, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line(stat='identity', size=0.75) +
  theme_bw() %+replace% theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill=NA)) +      
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +    
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank()) +     
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Phytoplankton")) +  
  theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill="white",colour="black")) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position=c(1,1), legend.justification = c(1, 1)) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10))  +        
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size =11)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('#e41a1c', '#377eb8', '#4daf4a', '#984ea3')) +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(color="black", size=0.2)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,365)) +
  scale_y_continuous(label=scientific) 
  plot(p1 + geom_rect(data=rect, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, 
  ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax), alpha=0.1, inherit.aes = FALSE))
```

Comment: Can you make your question reproducible or use one of the sample data sets within R?

Comment: try adding legend=F to your geom_rect i.e. `geom_rect(data=rect, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), alpha=0.1, inherit.aes=F, legend=F)` just a thought